# Android: customize all UI widgets using one theme

Tags: android, android-manifest

How can I customize all widgets in the application by creating one style and apply it to application through android:theme in AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this by creating just one style. A theme is in essence a meta-style that defines the default styles for each of the different widgets available. You will start by creating a theme (which is itself a style) with a parent of one of the existing system themes and setting the default style attributes for each widget you wish to change from the base theme. For example, if you had a different button style that you wanted to set as default in your theme, you might add the following to your theme definition:

```
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
```

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html for more info.

Comment: I did not noticed that *Style attributes. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that might help (it might not work verbatim as I've tweaked it to simplify it, and to showcase some of the other things you can do).

In res\values\styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="TextColorForTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

In res\values\themes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="myTheme" parent="@style/android:Theme">
    <item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/TextColorForTheme</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Then in your AndroidManifest.xml, set either the whole application, or individual Activities to use that theme:

```
  <application
    android:theme="@style/myTheme"
<snip>    
    <activity
      android:theme="@style/myTheme"
<snip>
```

Alternatively, you can set the theme in the code for your Java Activity:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
  {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setTheme(R.style.myTheme);
<snip>
```

Comment: Ok but it works globally, isn't it? What I would like to do is set a style separatly to ex. Button, TextField etc

Comment: A theme lets you apply a style to the whole application or Activity (that's what I thought your question was asking).  If you want to apply a style to individual UI elements then just use style:"@style:TextColorForTheme" in the XML for the object (e.g. the TextView).  See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html